# Question about AWS Prometheus tutorial

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, amazon-ecs

I'm following this cool example on how to run a container and monitor it CloudWatch with Prometheus - [Monitor and scale your Amazon ECS on AWS Fargate application using Prometheus metrics](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/monitor-and-scale-your-amazon-ecs-on-aws-fargate-application-using-prometheus-metrics/). All my services are running. However, when I get to the "Use metrics collected from Prometheus for automatic scaling" section, but I don't see the metrics defined in the `config.xml` file on that line, e.g., `tomcat_threadpool_connectioncount`. I just see the default metrics that AWS provides.

Has anyone done this tutorial? If so can you give me pointers on what I may have done wrong? I'm new to Prometheus, but not with AWS.